What is the format of the QR codes for pairing IoT devices?
Recent versions of Android offer an option to "Use a QR code to add a device to this network", whereby the Android device scans a QR code, and this (somehow) provides WiFi connection information to a nearby device.

There's a lot of confusion over this option, likely to its similarity to the WIFI: barcode format which a device can use to connect itself to a WiFi network.
My questions:

What exactly is the format of the QR codes which an Android device must scan in order to add a device to the local WiFi network?
How does this provisioning process work? How does the Android device find and connect to the IoT device? (My guess would be WiFi Direct and/or Bluetooth, but I'd like to know more details.)

I haven't been able to find any authoritative documentation on the subject.

Some pointers from Secret's Blog: DDP Protocol or Wi-Fi Easy Connect™.

Thank you! Since posting this, I had also figured out that it appears to be the same as DDP aka WiFi easy connect.
